# Pass data from main activity to SurfaceView thread using a seek bar

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview

I have a main activity class, I've also got a SurfaceView class that starts when my main activity starts.

I've got a seek bar in the main activity. I'd like to send whatever data that the seek bar produces to the SurfaceView to show it, every time it changes.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Here is my SurfaceView class:

```
public class SurfaceViewGauge extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{


 private MySurfaceThread thread;
 private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

 public SurfaceViewGauge(Context context) {
  super(context);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  init();
 }

 public SurfaceViewGauge(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  init();
 }

 public SurfaceViewGauge(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  init();
 }

  private void init(){
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    thread = new MySurfaceThread(getHolder(), this);

    setFocusable(true); // make sure we get key events

    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

   }

 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  thread.setRunning(true);
  thread.start();

 }

 public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  boolean retry = true;
  thread.setRunning(false);
  while (retry) {
   try {
    thread.join();
    retry = false;
   }
   catch (InterruptedException e) {
   }
  }
 }

 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }


}
```

And Here is my Thread class:

```
    public class MySurfaceThread extends Thread {
 private SurfaceHolder myThreadSurfaceHolder;
 private SurfaceViewGauge myThreadSurfaceView;
 private boolean myThreadRun = false;

 public MySurfaceThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, SurfaceViewGauge surfaceView) {
  myThreadSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
  myThreadSurfaceView = surfaceView;
 }

 public void setRunning(boolean b) {
  myThreadRun = b;
 }

 @Override
 public void run() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  while(myThreadRun){
   Canvas c = null;

   try{
    c = myThreadSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
    synchronized (myThreadSurfaceHolder){
     myThreadSurfaceView.onDraw(c);
    }
    sleep(0);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   finally{
    // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
    // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
    // inconsistent state
    if (c != null) {
     myThreadSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your MainActivity declare a static variable which will hold seekbar value and in your surfaceview code with the help of handler just call that static variable 
  e.g.

```
MainClass.seekValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Code, add Handler..

```
public Handler mhandler;

public SurfaceViewGauge(Context context, Handler mhandler) 
{
super(context);
this.mhandler = mhandler;
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
init();
}
```

In the above code, use the Handler object for sending the code.